# How to set vscode Rust tabsize as 4?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I add the following code in settings.json, but it doesn't work.

```json
"[Rust]": {
    "tabSize": 4
}
```

Comment: the languageID for Rust is `rust`

Comment: oh~ right, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Working json

```
"[rust]": {
  "editor.tabSize": 4
}
```

Easy way to navigate to language specific settings:

1. open any rust file (*.rs)
2. click in the bottom bar ***Rust***
3. in pop up window select ***Configure 'Rust' language base settings...***